# How to categorize strings from a text file

Tags: c++, text, iostream

I have a text file with a list of games and every 2 games are a different category

```
League Of Legends MMO
World Of Warcraft MMO
Civilization Strategy
Hearthstone Strategy
Street Fighter Arcade
PacMan Arcade
Beat Saber AR
Superhot AR
```

I have 4 child classes called MMO, Strategy, Arcade, and AR. Each of the categories (arcade, mmo, etc.) have their own polymorphic function to get the price such as adding a monthly fee etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Game {
    string Name;
    string Description;

    Game(string Name, string Description);

};

//PC inherits Game
class PC : public Game {
    string Name;
    string Description;

    PC():Game(Name,Description)
};

// MMO inherits PC
class MMO : public PC {
    string Name;
    string Description;
    double basePrice;
    double monthlyFee;

    MMO():PC(Name,Description)

    //Polymorphic function declaration
    virtual double getMonthlyCost() {

        monthlyFee = 14.99;
    }
};

//Strategy inherits PC
class Strategy : public PC {
    string Name;
    string Description;
    double basePrice;
    double monthlyFee;

    Strategy():PC(Name, Description)

    double getMonthlyCost() {
        basePrice* monthlyFee;
    }
};

class Console {
    string Name;
    string Description;

    Console(string Name, string Description);

};

//Arcade inherits Console
class Arcade : public Console {
    string Name;
    string Description;
    double basePrice;
    Arcade():Console(Name, Description)

    double getMonthlyCost() {

        basePrice + (basePrice * 0.10);
    }
};

//AR inherits Console
class AR : public Console {
    string Name;
    string Description;
    double costOfEquipment;
    double basePrice;

    AR():Console(Name, Description)

    double getMonthlyCost() {

        costOfEquipment + basePrice;
    }
};
```

My question is how would I go about sorting the games from the text file into their own respective categories so that they can be calculated using their respective getMonthlyCost function?

I'm open to any criticisms and comments!

Comment: The point of using virtual functions it that you **don't** have to sort and categorise the games, just create objects of the appropriate type and put into one big container. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Everyone of your `getMonthlyCost` functions is missing a return statement BTW. Your compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: You also need to add a virtual and possibly pure `getMonthlyCost` function to your `Game` base class, otherwise your virtual functions aren't going to work (at least they aren't going to work as virtual functions).

Comment: The main task I have with this project is to have all these games in a vector and sort the vector of games by price. My main issue is every game type has a different price calculation so I need to put the right games with the right polymorphic function if that makes any sense...

Comment: Yes it make sense, and you do that by creating objects of the correct type in the first place from your file. Is that the bit you are struggling with?

Comment: there are so many { and } missing in the code you give ...

Comment: It's a tricky file format to deal with because the information you need (the type of the game) is at the end of each line after a variable amount of data. There's also no price information in the file, so it's not clear how you can create any of the objects all of which require some price data. Are you able to adjust the file format? At the very least I'd move the type of game information to the beginning of each line.

Comment: @john Something along those lines I need to make sure each game is under their respective class using their respective polymorphic function.

Comment: @john I can put the category in front but how do I go about sorting them into their respective categories?

Comment: @James You're confusing me, one the one hand you say you want to sort a vector by price, fine that makes perfect sense. Then you say that you have to sort the games into categories, that's does not make sense. As I said earlier the point of polymorphism is that you **don't** have to categorise or sort the games by type. It's not necessary because you are using virtual functions.

Comment: Anyway there's no magic way to do this, you have to read the file information and then you have to do something like `if (type == "MMO") game = new MMO(name, description); else if (type == "Strategy") game = new Strategy(name, description); else ...` etc etc

Comment: @john Because each category of games are using polymorphic functions, I need to make sure each one is getting calculated correctly. So AR for example is basePrice+ priceOfEquipment so I need to make sure the correct games are getting calculated correctly

Comment: I understand that. I think maybe you don't understand polymorphic functions. **If** you create objects of the correct type **then** the correct polymorphic functions will get called. There is no need to sort or categorise your objects by type.

Comment: @James The way you are talking it's as if you aren't using polymorphic functions. In that case you would need to categorise your objects by type.

Comment: @john Yes I understand you now I was having a bit of a brain fart. How would I go about making new objects with what you gave me? Ill need to search line by line then for the categories and make objects right?

Comment: @James Pretty much, there's no quick or magic way to do it. Since you have control of the file format, take advantage and make it as easy for you to deal with as you can.

Comment: @john Just wanted to say thanks for being patient with me and helping me out!